# Select records having a time interval greater than a certain value in Teradata

Tags: teradata, sqldatetime

I am stuck with a simple problem related to finding out which queries took more than usual to complete. My script is the following:

```
locking row for access
SELECT 
username, 
CollectTimeStamp, 
((firstresptime - starttime  ) HOUR TO second  ) AS ElapsedTime,
((firstresptime - firststeptime  ) HOUR  TO second ) AS ExecutionTime,
CAST(((firstresptime - firststeptime) SECOND) AS INTEGER) AS ExecutionTimeInt,
(ElapsedTime - ExecutionTime) AS Delay, 
-- other kpis here
FROM dbql_data.dbql_all
where username ='MyUser'; 
and dateofday> '2017-07-01'
    and ExecutionTimeInt > 5
```

However, I get records having `ExecutionTimeInt` less than 5.

**Question:** how can I get the records having a timeinterval greater than a certain value?

Extra info:

`select * from dbc.dbcinfo;` returns

```
    InfoKey InfoData
1   VERSION 15.10.04.10
2   RELEASE 15.10.04.02
3   LANGUAGE SUPPORT MODE   Standard
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ExecutionTimeInt` calculation is likely to fail with an `Interval overflow` as it's limited to 9999 seconds.

`ElapsedTime` is an Interval, the correct way to compare is:

```
WHERE ElapsedTime > interval '5' second
```

or

```
WHERE ElapsedTime > interval '1' minute
```

Comment: In my particular case, there is a very small chance to have more than 9999 seconds, since all queries are issued using Teradata.Net client and I have a timeout of maximum 600 seconds. Anyway, I have tried the first suggestion (`WHERE ElapsedTime > interval '5' second`) and I still receive what it appears to be smaller values like `  0:00:00.020000`).

Comment: @Alexei: If this is your actual query remove the `;` after `where username ='MyUser';` :-)

Comment: Damn. Missed that in SQL Assistant. It works without it, of course. Thanks.

Comment: @Alexei: Been here, done that: `delete from acclogtbl; where logdate > current_date - 500` :-)

Comment: well, the SQL Assistant's font which sometimes merges the characters favors this kind of events; not stopping at syntax errors (like other tools do) also favors this.

Comment: @Alexei: That's why I always switch the font to the real programmer's font *Courier New* :-)  Regarding syntax errors: Switch to *.Net* and it will jump to the position the parser choked and show that *red, wavy underline*